# Wrong number of arguments (5 for 1..4) in Rails select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Running into an issue when passing arguments in `select` in Rails:

> wrong number of arguments (5 for 1..4)

Here's the code:

```
<dd><%= f.select :codes, options_for_select(CarParts::CODES), {include_blank: "Select Code"}, {required: true}, {}, {onchange: "myFunc(this);"} %></dd>
```

Removing the empty hash returns the same error. Though removing both the `include_blank` and `required` attribute while keeping it there seems to work correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: The [`select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) method takes at most four arguments, the last two of which are hashes. You're passing six arguments, four of which are hashes. "Removing the empty hash" still leaves you with one too many arguments. I suggest reading the linked documentation and narrowing down what values you actually want to pass.

Comment: Thanks @Jordan - do you have any other suggestions on how to accomplish this with keeping all the functionality?

Comment: @ethrowin it's unclear what functionality you think you're getting here. You do not have to pass each key/value pair of attributes as its own hash. Group them. The documentation will tell you which options go in which argument.

Comment: There's no trick to it. There's an `options` hash and an `html_options` hash. All of your options go in one or the other. Like @meagar said, the docs tell you which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
<dd><%= f.select :codes, options_for_select(CarParts::CODES), { include_blank: "Select Code" }, { required: true, onchange: "myFunc(this);"} %></dd>
```

The `include_blank` goes in `options` and the `required` and `onchange` are HTML options.  Here's the API documentation for the [Form Helper `select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) for reference and examples.